# Efficient time series correlation calculation?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

My data looks like so;

```
[Date, Product, Sales]
01-01, A, 3
01-02, A, 0
01-03, A, 2
...
01-01, Z, 10
01-02, Z, 11
01-03, Z, 13
```

I'm trying to find products that share very similar/dissimilar selling patterns within my data. My current solutions is as follows. I'm calculating the Pearson correlation coefficient of the sales for every one of my products compared to all of the others;

```
df = pd.DataFrame(..., columns=[Date, Product, Sales])
products = df.Products.unique()
correlations = []

for i in range(len(products)):
    a = df[df.Product == products[i]]

    for j in range(i+1, len(products)):
        b = df[df.Product == products[j]]
        
        *inner join a and b on Date to ensure we have the same dates as some data can be missing*
        
        correlations.append(a.corr(b))  # Pandas built in pearson correlation method on the sales columns
```

I have around 10k products right now and the inner join date intersection can result in around 2k dates maximum overlap. So the complexity of the above is technically len(products) * len(products) * dates which is quite a large number. The current run time for my query is around 30 hours. However I can't seem to shake the feeling that this could be done much more efficiently. I added threading to the inner loop which didn't really improve the performance at all.

So I'm turning to you to help! Please drop a reply if you have any ideas for how to optimize this code further. :)

**Edit**: As requested, I'll elaborate a bit more with an example.

Let's say we have 3 products in our data set; A, B and C.

[Date, Product, Sales]

```
01-01, A, 3
01-02, A, 0
01-03, A, 2

01-01, B, 2
01-02, B, 0
01-03, B, 3

01-01, C, 0
01-02, C, 4
01-03, C, 0
```

What I want to do is to find out how sales correlate between different products. I'm interested in both positive correlation (curves behave simialrly) and negative correlation (curves behave completely opposite) as both contain valuable information.

Walking through the code loop, our first product in the outer loop would be product A. A would be compared to B and C within the inner loops. As you can see A is very similar to B (both have positive sales on date 1 and 3, and 0 sales on date 2) which will result in a Pearson correlation value very close to 1. A is however very dissimilar to C (the selling is essentially inverted) and the Pearson correlation will therefore be close to -1.

Knowing this correlation is interesting to me so I can analyze cannibalization effects and other trends between products. My plan is to select the top and bottom X correlated articles for every article and pass it one to some other decision logic.

Comment: It seems like you're treating time as the independent variable, and calculating cross-correlation of each product as a function of time. I have my severe doubts as to whether that's meaningful. Typically you'd want to, for example, calculate correlation of which products appear in the same _order_.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure I'm following what you mean by "which products appear in the same order". Can you give me an example either as to how the code would be different or just try to describe it?
The analysis I'm doing is for an experiment and I think it could be valid. Similar historical selling patterns on the same dates could provide information about future similarities/dissimilarrities.

Comment: Two products selling on the same day means very little. Two products being sold to the same person at the same time means more. If you were to add an order number column and group on that, that would be a start.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this is not really what I'm interested in. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can pivot your dataframe before:

```
df1 = df.pivot(index='Date', columns='Product', values='Sales')
corr = df1.corr(method='pearson')
```

Output:

```
>>> corr
Product         A         B         C
Product                              
A        1.000000  0.785714 -0.944911
B        0.785714  1.000000 -0.944911
C       -0.944911 -0.944911  1.000000

>>> df1
Product  A  B  C
Date            
01-01    3  2  0
01-02    0  0  4
01-03    2  3  0
```

Comment: Absolutely amazing! Execution finished in just a few minutes and the pandas corr method even properly ignore dthe nans (which I had a ton of problems with before and why I had to do the inner join on dates inside the for-loop). Big thanks!

Comment: In case you (or anyone else) knows the reason for why pivoting the data and then applying the corr method was that much more efficient, I'd be very happy to hear the explanation.

Comment: The answer is simple. With `pivot`, you have no loop and the `corr` method is vectorized. In your code you have 2 nested loops then you subset your dataframe 2 times per loop (copy data is slow). `list.append` is slow (you should use a dict like `d[p1, p2]`), etc.

Comment: Hm, yeah, actually I had indexed the DF on "product" so that should take no time. Dict is probably a better idea than list appending as well.
I guess corr is only vectorized over the set of overlapping dates for one product compared to another in my for-loop solution. Whereas in the pivoting solution, the vectorized set is the full data which means every product x product x date multiplication is vectorized.